# How to uninstall msi non interactivelly and silently

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am installing an msi with a powershell script and I also want to remove it the same way.
I have basically used the same method as when installing but changed i to x and qb to q in params.

```
$params = '/x', "$myGUID", '/q'
$p = Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $params -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

This gives me a fatal error with exitcode `1603`

When not using `'/q'` it will succeed but it will also require me to interact with a promt asking me if I really want to uninstall.

How do I force it to silently uninstall without any interactions?

Comment: have you tried changing `$params = '/x', "$myGUID", '/q'` to `$params = '/x', $myGUID, '/q'`
I've had issues before passing GUIDs as strings and passing just the variable worked for me

Comment: I'd say that `/q` isn't valid option (see `msiexec -?` ). Use either `/quiet` or equivalent `/qn` instead ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options))